# instagram.com/api/v1/news/ -> stopped working. returns "MOVED PERMANENTLY" or "upgrade instagram'

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I used to access `instagram.com/api/v1/news/`  through a desktop browser, it suddenly stopped working and instead returned "Please upgrade Instagram to the latest version."

So i tried to access it via api and it instead returns 'moved permanently HTTP 301'.

Does anyone know to where it has moved, or otherwise have a solution to access it via desktop? (that doesn't involve using an android emulator).

Comment: Did you try with /v2/ or /v3/, etc? They seem to exist (although they give me an error because I'm not logged in). Also, http 301 should include the new location of the page being moved. If you can capture the full http header, maybe you'll see where it's pointing you to.

Comment: instagram.com/api/v1/news/ is working for me